# How to separate bash prompt + command from output with a blank line?

Tags: bash, command-prompt, prompt

In bash, I would like to separate the prompt + command from the command output with a single empty line.

In addition, I would also like the output to also be followed by a single blank line.

For instance, instead of this:

```
$ ls
  file1  file2  file3
  file4  file5  file6
$
```

I would like to see this:

```
$ ls
                           <--- empty line
  file1  file2  file3
  file4  file5  file6
                           <--- empty line
$
```

Ideally, no line (or just one line) would be skipped if output is empty.

Answer (score 2):

This gets you pretty close (requires Bash 4.4 or newer for [`PS0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS0)):

```
PS1=$'\n'$PS1; PS0=$'\n'
```

The change to `PS1` inserts a blank line before the prompt, and `PS0` is displayed after reading a command, but before it is executed:

```
$ ls

file01  file02  file03  file04  file05  file06  file07  file08  file09  file10

$
```